# How do I pass arguments to the resolve method when using Swinject?

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, swinject

I have a test project that I'm trying to pass an argument to the resolve method in a [Swinject](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject) project.

Here is an example of what my Swinject storyboard extetion file has in it.

```
import Swinject

extension SwinjectStoryboard {

    class func setup() {

        let mainDm = MainDM()

        defaultContainer.register(MainDM.self) { _ in
            mainDm
        }

        defaultContainer.registerForStoryboard(ViewController.self) { r, c in
            c.dm = r.resolve(MainDM.self)
            c.container = defaultContainer

        }


        defaultContainer.register(GetMessageAction.self) { _, delegate in
            GetMessageAction(dm:mainDm, delegate: delegate)
        }

    }

}
```

in my ViewController I'm trying to do the following to resolve the GetMessageAction

```
@IBOutlet weak var myText: UILabel!

    var dm:MainDM!
    var container:Container!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(3), target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.getMessage), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    }

    func getMessage() {

        let action:GetMessageAction? = container.resolve(GetMessageAction.self, argument: self)!
        action?.execute()

    }
```

I get the following message when my getMessage function runs

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 3):

As resolving with arguments is dependent on exactly matching types of arguments, you need to downcast passed object:

```
container.resolve(GetMessageAction.self, argument: self as GetMessageActionDelegate)!
```

Assuming that `GetMessageActionDelegate` is the type of delegate passed in constructor `GetMessageAction(dm:delegate:)`.

Comment: doing this I still get the following error 

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 1):

The swift file of the ViewController you have created in your Storyboard **must declare init(NSCoder)**, it is actually not mentioned in the README.md, I'm thinking about opening an issue regarding this...

```
   required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
```

You can take a look at my [open source project using exactly this technique](https://github.com/Sajjon/SwiftIntro), I am setting up the dependencies using the [extension of SwinjectStoryboard here](https://github.com/Sajjon/SwiftIntro/blob/master/SwiftIntro/SupportingFiles/DependencyInjectionConfigurator.swift) for example the [LoadingDataVC](https://github.com/Sajjon/SwiftIntro/blob/master/SwiftIntro/ViewControllers/LoadingDataVC.swift).

```
extension SwinjectStoryboard {
    class func setup() {

        defaultContainer.register(HTTPClientProtocol.self) { _ in
            HTTPClient()
        }.inObjectScope(.Container)

        defaultContainer.register(APIClientProtocol.self) { r in
            APIClient(
                httpClient: r.resolve(HTTPClientProtocol.self)!
            )
        }.inObjectScope(.Container)

        defaultContainer.register(ImagePrefetcherProtocol.self) { _ in
            ImagePrefetcher()
        }.inObjectScope(.Container)

        defaultContainer.registerForStoryboard(GameVC.self) { r, c in
            c.imagePrefetcher = r.resolve(ImagePrefetcherProtocol.self)
        }

        defaultContainer.registerForStoryboard(LoadingDataVC.self) { r, c in
            c.apiClient = r.resolve(APIClientProtocol.self)
            c.imagePrefetcher = r.resolve(ImagePrefetcherProtocol.self)
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have the required init it should work! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use either of the following methods of a storyboard to get a view controller registered by `registerForStoryboard`.

- `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`
- `instantiateInitialViewController`

https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/blob/v1/Documentation/Storyboard.md
https://github.com/Swinject/SwinjectStoryboard/issues/5

Comment: This doesn't explain why I can't pass an argument to the resolve(GetMessageAction.self, argument:self)

Comment: I'm sorry for my misunderstanding. I didn't have time to read your question carefully.

Comment: I think you instantiated `ViewController` by its initializer, not by `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` or `instantiateInitialViewController`. That's why `container` property of `ViewController` did not get injected and you got the error. If you use the either of `instantiate*` methods, I think `resolve` method for `GetMessageAction` with the argument should work because the `container` property is injected and it is not `nil`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and followed documentation and for whatever reason this is still not working. If I inspect the container in the ViewController I see the services and keys to all the objects but it's not returning my class. Could you have a look at my project in order to get more context and see what I might be doing wrong ? 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqjrn5b1ysyautm/Hello%20MVC.zip?dl=0